# Data extraction from HEC-RAS

Tags: python, extract, data-modeling, hec-ras

I'm using Hec-Ras for 2D unsteady modeling of a river delta. My model is simulated for one year. I need to extract the velocities and/or discharges and compare them with the velocities from a already done 1DSA model. I wanted to do it in python but I'm new in programming and I wanted to see if anyone has experience with this kind of problem or has any idea on how I can compare the results the easiest because there is a big amount of data and manually doing it from the ras mapper would take a lot of time.

Comment: you can read the hdf result files using h5py package which will allow you to probe results in different cells, to get results at a profile line (2d equivalent of 1d XS) you might be able to make one in rasmapper and save/rerun everything, and see if those results save into the hdf file?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can use vector data, first with a classified and get different values between areas, after a statistical analysis.